# What's the name of this anime

Tags: story-identification, anime

[image: Anime image of a darkhaired man with purple eyes holding up his hand while purple light streaks encircle him]

I was searching for an anime recommendation and I found this photo in a video thumbnail. I've asked what anime it is in the comments but still haven't gotten an answer despite me waiting 2 weeks. So I'm hoping someone would help me find it.

Comment: Once you join, if someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

I believe that is [Takt Ashima](https://takt-op.fandom.com/wiki/Takt_Asahina) from [*Takt op. Destiny*](https://takt-op.fandom.com/wiki/Takt_op._Destiny_-_Anime).

> Music is the light in the hearts of man...
>
> Suddenly, this "light" was taken away from this world. One night, dark meteorites called the "Iron Nocturne" fell from the sky, and the world changed since then. From these meteorites sprung forth grotesque monsters called "D2" which overrun the earth and its people. The D2 are attracted to the music played by humans, and soon "music" itself became a taboo.
>
> But, those who can fight these monsters soon appeared. Girls who can use music as their weapons—the "Musicarts". These girls can imbue themselves with the scores of the great operas and compositions from history and use this as power to defeat the D2. And, the Conductor commands these girls and lead the way.
>
> The year 2047. America, now destroyed due to the resistance against the D2. The Conductor Takt travels to New York with the Musicart Destiny. In this world that had lost its music, Takt, who thirsts for music, and Destiny, the Musicart who desires the annihilation of the D2. The melody they create, will it lead them to bliss or to despair?

### Opening

Doing a reverse image search brought up [this page](https://nitter.domain.glass/i/status/1445255405546852352) with this image:

[image: Image of Takt Ashima with his fingers up against a car window]